# They said I had no oil or coolant in my 2016 Elantra

Tags: engine, hyundai

I have a 2016 Hyundai Elantra  with 44,500 miles and I had an oil change in July. My car never showed that I was low on oil or coolant and now the dealership is saying that they had to put 4 qts of oil in and that my car slipped timing and I have no compression.

If I was that low why didn't my light come on and let me know I was low?

Comment: Does your car have the 1.8 liter engine (SE, Limited, Value Edition) or the 2.0 liter engine (Sport model)?

Comment: So how was the car driving before you sent it into the dealership? did you just go for an oil change or was there a problem before hand?

Comment: I call shenanigans. No way the car would have not alerted you. How do they know it slipped timing? Did they check the timing chain/belt?

Comment: Zaid's point below is a good one.  There's a good chance that any of this is covered by the warranty.

Comment: Sounds like the dealer is trying to put the blame on you and avoid doing warranty work. Did you do the previous oil change(July) at the dealership as well? or did you take it somewhere else?

Comment: How did the oil and coolant levels look last time you checked?  At what mileage was this?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this owner's manual](https://carmanuals2.com/hyundai/elantra-2016-owner-s-manual-75352), the 2016 Elantra needs 4.23 qts (page 651 in PDF).

I don't see a dedicated "Low oil level" warning light on the instrument cluster, just an Engine Oil Pressure Warning Light (page 151 of PDF). I would expect that such a low amount of oil would trigger the low oil pressure light, but it really depends on how much oil is present in the oil pan.

The Engine Oil Pressure Warning Light looks like this:

[image: Low Oil Pressure Light]

### But...

Isn't this vehicle supposed to be under warranty? Slipped timing, loss of compression on a brand new engine ought to be covered by warranty.

If that oil pressure light did not turn on, there is no way for you to reasonably tell whether the car was low on oil to begin with.

Also, to lose 4 quarts in less than three months implies an oil leak of epic proportions. Could it be that someone forgot to put on the oil cap during the last service? A picture of the engine bay in its present state would help confirm/rule out such a possibility.

Comment: The oil pressure light certainly should have come on.  It must have failed.

Comment: @DucatiKiller in which case any damage should be covered by warranty

Comment: That would be the inference.

Comment: In the USA, the default Hyundai warranty is 5 year, 60000 miles.  I'm pretty sure that @Zaid is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am on the hook for my 2014 santa fe 2.0L complete engine failure......the inspection to determine such was pulling my dip stick and an external check for leaks.
They have found sludge (please don't insult me like hyundai did claiming I have NEVER done an oil change on a BRAND NEW vehicle) and if they find any in yours, they will deny ALL warranty.
They will not tell me what broke or didn't break in the engine, just and I quote.."best guess is the sludge will be in entire engine and best guess is full engine replacement."
If your oil pressure light and engine light came on.....it's like the red circle of death of for the XBOX 360.

Also the intervals of your oil changes will be brought into question.  Was told by my sales rep at time of purchase 7500 km between changes on full synthetic was recommended.   If you read your manual it will say anywhere from 3000 to 7500..... read more carefully and it explains why the intervals change....  so I have a turbo that obviously had blow by to empty my oil, hyundai won't even look at said Turbo.

They have a million sub clauses that get them out of warranty.
My car first when in January....they said I needed a new short block and could not or would not tell me what actually failed....this time it's in they say sludge and complete rebuild or engine replacement.....due to discovery of sludge.
Before you all beat me up again, look into turbo blow by, and the high carbon count it creates in your engine....blow by is oil being forced through turbo, over your manifolds and out the exhaust.

Also look up Theta II problem engine.  Hyundai willing and knowingly put these defective engines in their vehicles and hide behind "low field reports of this failure".  One their own techs (of 25 yrs) came out and warned the world.....he was dismissed August 2016.

Stay on them...........